When debugging in VS 2022 DateTime shows {System.DateTime} on mouseover
I am using Visual Studio 2022 Professional, version 17.9.0.
Also using ReSharper, CodeMaid and GitHub CoPilot in addition to some other extensions.
For some time I have seen that when I am debugging, and want to see what date a DateTime variable is set to, it only shows "{System.DateTime}" and not the actual date.

It's the same in the watch windows.

This (someone else's) question was solved by removing a pin on the Kind property of DateTime: Showing DateTime .ToString() in debug VS 2022
But I don't have any pinned properties on my DateTime. If there was a Type-property I would guess it could be pinned but it does not show up in the watch window when I look at DateTime.Now.
I also have enabled the "Call string-conversion function on objects in variable windows" setting.
In the Watch window, when I use the "ToString()" function on my variable, it shows the date as I would expect. Why is VS not calling the string conversion function implicitly?
I am using a workaround which is to pin the Year, Month and Day. But it's a little bit more cumbersome to read.
Some of my colleagues have the same problem.
Update:

It does remove the problem temporarily to 1) disable "Property evaluation and other implicit function calls", 2) restart Visual Studio, and 3) re-enable "Property evaluation and other implicit function calls".
Doing the above without restarting VS does not work.
The problem comes back after a short time debugging with some debug sessions.
It is possible that the problem started after I started using GitHub CoPilot, so that might be the culprit.

So any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Can you include a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Ok, I've added some pictures.

Have you tried turning it off and on again by disabling and re-enabling both the "Call string-conversion function on objects in varables windows" along with it's parent "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls"?

Ok, thanks that worked! :) Just turned off the options, then restarted VS, and then reenabled the options, and then restarted again. Please add your solution so I can accept it?

This is weird, I didn't have to restart VS myself. It feels like either a bug or something else is going on here.

The chances are that something has got confused in the settings and you should try turning it off and on again!.
Try disabling and re-enabling both the "Call string-conversion function on objects in varables windows" along with it's parent "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" under Debugging -> General.


Thanks, it works to turn it off and on, but I often put my computer into hibernate mode, and now once I've resumed, it is back to not showing actual dates. Guess I must restart again. SO the problem is not really solved.

It works to 1) disable the "Enable property..." setting, 2) Restart VS, 3) enable the setting again. I will test next time it happens if it also works without restarting VS.

Suddenly, without any hibernate or anything in between, it now is bad again. And turning it off and on without restarting VS does not work.

Sorry, the problem was not solved, so I am removing the accepted solution.

Fair enough, it seems that something else is interfereing with the setting!

For me, worked but only for a short while, then it just stopped working again. Weird bug.
